# Where's php_memcached.dll available now?

Tags: php, memcached

I can only find `php_memcache.dll`,can't find `php_memcached.dll` after searching for several hours...

Comment: One is for `Memcache` class,the other is for `Memcached`,which I'm looking for..

Comment: `php_memcached.dll` is for client side,but memcached.org only provides the memcache server.

Comment: The problem is there's no `php_memcached.dll` extension over the interweb...

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:  `memcached-client` from https://github.com/fwolf/memcached-client:

"As there has no php memcached extension for windows now, it's difficult to build develop envionment, so this class will be helpful.

Inspried by: http://github.com/joonas-fi/xslib-memcached"

**Usage:**

Just as php_memcached extension, new Memcached object and etc.

```
$m = new Memcached();
$m->addServer('localhost', 11211);

$m->set('foo', 'bar');
$m->get('foo');
```

**Supported method:**

```
addServer
addServers
delete
get
getOption
getResultCode
getResultMessage
getServerList
set
setOption
setOptions
```

Answer (score 1):

Trail of links from the manual page in reverse chronological order:

http://libmemcached.org/
http://tangent.org/
https://github.com/andreiz/php-memcached
http://pecl.php.net/package/memcached
http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcached.installation.php

There's a broken link to http://tangent.org/552/libmemcached.html in between that somebody should update though.

Seems like only the source code is available and you'll have to compile it yourself.

Comment: Oh no...compile it myself is almost impossible in windows...

Comment: Seems like there's almost no other solution. There indeed doesn't appear to be a downloadable binary win32 build.

Answer (score -2):

you can found here  http://windows.php.net/

There are several versions of php_memcache.dll, the right one will depend on your version of PHP. 
you should download according to your php version

Comment: Note the `d` in memcached