# memcache not showing in phpinfo()

Tags: php, xampp, memcached

I've followed each step to install and start memcache in windows. Didn't found any memcache.exe file(some tutorials told to use memcached.exe, so used it from link:http://downloads.northscale.com/memcached-win32-1.4.4-14.zip)

Executing following command in cmd with admin rights:

> net start "memcached"

shows "The memcached service is starting. The memcached service was started successfully."

But result of phpinfo() does not show any memcache detail. Moreover php code is unable to find "memcahed" or "memcache" class.

I'm working on windows, using xampp(32bits).

`PHP version 5.6.24
OS: Windows 8.1
Architecture: x86
Thread safety: enabled`

Things already done:

-> added "extension=php_memcache.dll" to php.ini file(located at \xampp\php\php.ini)

-> verified locations of "extension_dir" variable and "php_memcache.dll"
-> no php_memcache.dll for version 5.2.0 was available, so tried with different versions but didn't work

->verified that both php and .dll are thread safe(TS).

Please let me know what I'm missing out?

Comment: You restarted apache after modifying PHP.ini, correct?

Comment: yes done several times. @MattClark

Comment: The answer to this question might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39107027/how-to-install-php-7-extension-memcached-on-windows

Comment: already done steps mentioned in that link, i've made changes in correct php.ini file and if there is issue with the version, no php_mecached.dll found for php5.2.0 and all other link for memcached.exe is invalid now. @jotaelesalinas