# phpinfo doesnt show memcache

Tags: php, memcached

I have some trouble to enable memcache. I'm running Debian 9 and installed memcache. It looks like everything is working

```
~$ ps aux | grep memcached
memcache  2341  0.0  0.0 335696  2648 ?        Ssl  18:57   0:01 /usr/bin/memcached -m 64 -p 11211 -u memcache -l 127.0.0.1
olafHus   7486  0.0  0.0  12788   972 pts/1    S+   21:41   0:00 grep memcached
```

I've checked if the module is enabled:

```
~$ sudo cat /etc/php5/conf.d/20-memcached.ini 
; uncomment the next line to enable the module
extension=memcached.so
```

Moreover, I also get

```
~$ sudo netstat -tap | grep memcached
tcp        0      0 localhost:11211         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2341/memcached
```

and finally I've run a `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`, `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload` and s`udo /etc/init.d/memcached restart`. But when I'm checking my localhost where a simple `phpinfo()` is located memcache is not listed. I've followed [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-memcache-on-ubuntu-14-04) instruction and put the following file to see if memcache is working

```
<?php
$mem = new Memcached();
$mem->addServer("127.0.0.1", 11211);

$result = $mem->get("blah");

if ($result) {
    echo $result;
} else {
    echo "No matching key found.  I'll add that now!";
    $mem->set("blah", "I am data!  I am held in memcached!") or die("Couldn't save anything to memcached...");
}
?>
```

But it doesn't work. Does someone know what's going on and how I can make memcache work?

EDIT:

This is the output of the log

```
$ sudo cat /var/log/apache2/error.log
[Mon Jul 10 18:23:10.671404 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 29979:tid 140044669715648] AH00489: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jul 10 18:23:10.671544 2017] [core:notice] [pid 29979:tid 140044669715648] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Jul 10 18:23:27.115014 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 29979:tid 140044669715648] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Jul 10 18:23:27.170643 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4817] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jul 10 18:23:27.170737 2017] [core:notice] [pid 4817] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Jul 10 18:23:27.447314 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4817] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Jul 10 18:23:27.536634 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4873] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jul 10 18:23:27.536680 2017] [core:notice] [pid 4873] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Jul 10 18:26:41.201787 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4873] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Jul 10 18:26:41.292588 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 6922] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jul 10 18:26:41.292635 2017] [core:notice] [pid 6922] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Jul 10 18:27:35.149322 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 6922] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Jul 10 18:27:35.244846 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 6981] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jul 10 18:27:35.244889 2017] [core:notice] [pid 6981] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Jul 10 18:29:32.870011 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 6981] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Jul 10 18:29:32.960699 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 26042] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jul 10 18:29:32.960738 2017] [core:notice] [pid 26042] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Jul 10 18:29:54.322087 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 26042] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Jul 10 18:29:54.416333 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 26089] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jul 10 18:29:54.416371 2017] [core:notice] [pid 26089] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Jul 10 18:32:55.998398 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 26089] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Jul 10 18:32:56.092397 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 30053] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jul 10 18:32:56.092431 2017] [core:notice] [pid 30053] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Jul 10 18:37:17.489919 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 30053] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Jul 10 18:37:17.586762 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 30260] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jul 10 18:37:17.586801 2017] [core:notice] [pid 30260] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Jul 10 18:37:21.451096 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 30260] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Jul 10 18:37:24.067553 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 30343] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jul 10 18:37:24.067594 2017] [core:notice] [pid 30343] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Jul 10 18:38:51.583610 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 30343] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Jul 10 18:38:53.488078 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 30595] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jul 10 18:38:53.488121 2017] [core:notice] [pid 30595] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Jul 10 18:39:59.404361 2017] [:error] [pid 30597] [client 127.0.0.1:38144] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Memcached' not found in /var/www/html/cache_test.php on line 2
[Mon Jul 10 18:39:59.404388 2017] [:error] [pid 30597] [client 127.0.0.1:38144] PHP Stack trace:
[Mon Jul 10 18:39:59.404394 2017] [:error] [pid 30597] [client 127.0.0.1:38144] PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/html/cache_test.php:0
[Mon Jul 10 18:40:05.482553 2017] [:error] [pid 30598] [client 127.0.0.1:38146] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Memcached' not found in /var/www/html/cache_test.php on line 2
[Mon Jul 10 18:40:05.482595 2017] [:error] [pid 30598] [client 127.0.0.1:38146] PHP Stack trace:
[Mon Jul 10 18:40:05.482607 2017] [:error] [pid 30598] [client 127.0.0.1:38146] PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/html/cache_test.php:0
[Mon Jul 10 18:46:58.898526 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 30595] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Jul 10 18:46:59.004874 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 31027] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jul 10 18:46:59.004915 2017] [core:notice] [pid 31027] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Jul 10 18:51:21.595950 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 31027] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Jul 10 18:51:21.692445 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 31243] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jul 10 18:51:21.692480 2017] [core:notice] [pid 31243] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Jul 10 18:54:33.454240 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 31243] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Jul 10 18:54:33.539549 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2072] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jul 10 18:54:33.539598 2017] [core:notice] [pid 2072] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Jul 10 18:54:41.149185 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2072] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Jul 10 18:54:41.244007 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2115] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jul 10 18:54:41.244039 2017] [core:notice] [pid 2115] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Jul 10 18:54:45.901404 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2115] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Mon Jul 10 18:54:45.922983 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2115] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jul 10 18:54:45.922999 2017] [core:notice] [pid 2115] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Mon Jul 10 18:58:37.287228 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2115] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Jul 10 18:58:37.381938 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2524] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jul 10 18:58:37.381994 2017] [core:notice] [pid 2524] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Comment: A case very similar to yours:: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39107027/how-to-install-php-7-extension-memcached-on-windows/39107783#39107783

Comment: @vanderHobus but isnt the problem there windows related?

Comment: Do any errors appear in php error log after you (re)start Apache? Also is `memcached.so` present on your system?

Comment: @JiriHrazdil no seems to be ok (see edit). I tried the cache_test but it failed telling me basically it's not working

Comment: Does the output of `phpinfo()` mention `/etc/php5/conf.d/20-memcached.ini` in the section _Additional .ini files parsed_?

Comment: @JiriHrazdil No it doesn't mention it.

Comment: That means that the file is not parsed, resulting in `memcached.so` extension not being loaded...

Comment: @JiriHrazdil how can I parse it?

Comment: I'm not sure how to correctly handle this on Debian, but you can add `extension=memcached.so` to your main `php.ini` file to see if it loads...

Comment: In the output of `phpinfo()` there is an item called _Scan this dir for additional .ini files_. This is the directory where the `20-memcached.ini` file should be located...